# Running Logstash on EC2 error='Cannot allocate memory'

Tags: amazon-ec2, logstash

I have been running logstash on a micro instance and have set

export LS_JAVA_OPTS=“-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:ParallelGCThreads=1” in .bashrc

It has been working for a while until now with the below error.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000c5330000, 986513                               408, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 986513408 bytes for committing reserved memor                               y.

# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 986513408 bytes for committing reserved memory.



Memory: 4k page, physical 1009132k(152316k free), swap 0k(0k free)
```